# JSON encoded unicode in http response not recognized on Linux/MAC but is on Windows?

Tags: json, linux, macos, http, unicode

On windows 7, firefox/chrome this url: http://api.crossref.org/works/10.1007/bf01282841 will return JSON with a value for "title" that contains encoded unicode "\u201c" and "\u201d". The "title" shows as

...\u201cOgneupornerud\u201d...

However, on Ubuntu 14.10 and Mac OSX, firefox/chrome the same url will return "?" instead of the encoded unicode. Instead the "title" shows as

...?Ogneupornerud?...

The same problem is replicated if I use CURL.

How to get ubuntu/mac to allow these encoded unicode to come through the http response?

EDIT:

What is strange is that another URL from the same host works for the same unicode. I am now more confused. On a mac and linux the following url will return back the encoded unicode characters no problem: http://api.crossref.org/works/10.1038/jid.2009.449

Comment: I don't believe that the first JSON is encoded correctly. Put the *nix output through `od -c` to see what bytes it actually contains.

Comment: FWIW: for me the first link contains question marks (actual ASCII question marks, not decoding errors) in all browsers including Win7 Chrome/Firefox.

Comment: When I use FireFox in Win7 x64, I also see the question marks in the actual transmitted JSON from the first URL, but see encoded Unicode characters from the second URL. So the problem with the first URL is definitely server-side, not client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first payload contains actual question marks. This likely is caused by the code writing the payload isn't properly configured for UTF-8.

Another nit: the media type contains a charset parameter, but that is undefined (and pointless) for application/json.

Comment: Yes, now when i make the request from my windows machine it is also displaying question marks. I swear that the encoded unicode was coming through, now makes me agree that this is server side. Thanks.